# Issue with TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Tags: python, typeerror

For the below code snippet, I receive the error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict`.

`coin['orderBooks'][i]` is indeed a dict, but how can I remove/delete it then? I need to remove from my dataset for further analysis.

```
#check if bid_price or ask_price exists, if not remove it from orderbooks
for coin in orderbooks:
    for i in coin['orderBooks']:
        bid_price = i['orderBook']['bids']
        ask_price = i['orderBook']['asks']
        if bid_price == [] or ask_price == []:
            del coin['orderBooks'][i]
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-47-07d8008d3d9c>", line 6, in <module>
    del coin['orderBooks'][i]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding, the `coin['orderBooks'][i]` is not a `dict` (it even throws the error), the `i` is an error, you should name it differently, as you access `i['orderBook']` you see it's a dict, and to delete it you may use it's index in the array

It would be like :

```
for coin in orderbooks:
    for idx, val in enumerate(coin['orderBooks']):
        bid_price = val['orderBook']['bids']
        ask_price = val['orderBook']['asks']
        if not bid_price or not ask_price:
            del coin['orderBooks'][idx]
```

But as remove while iterating is not a really good idea, you may *keep the good ones*, with a loop comprehension that's easy

```
for coin in orderbooks:
    coin['orderBooks'] = [val for val in coin['orderBooks'] 
                              if val['orderBook']['bids'] and val['orderBook']['askas']]
```

---

Also you can check for empty list directly with its bool value (`bool([]) == False`)

Comment: I think deleting entries as you iterate through the list will cause problems. Best to build a new list with only good values.